# Program to switch display from monitor to TV (and back)

Tags: windows, winapi, multiple-monitors

I frequently switch my desktop from the LCD monitor to the TV (HDMI output from an Nvidia 660 gtx) and back. To do this is fairly cumbersome - and I want to make it very simple for the kids too. Currently I have to right click the desktop -> Screen resolution -> Multiple Displays -> Show desktop only on 1 -> ok. Then go to the TV and click ok on the 'is this resolution ok' prompt.

I'd like one button - and preferably no prompt on the other device.

Any idea what part of the windows API I need to be looking at? Maybe I can do it through a shell command?

Any pointers would be welcome as I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

There is a keyboard shortcut in Windows 7 which may do what you want.... Windows + P

Answer (score 0):

I have found 3 different links that describe possible solutions for your problem. An [monitor switcher application in WPF](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?249459-C-WPF-Monitor-Switcher), [a description for windows xp](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/178027/How-to-create-a-display-switcher-for-Windows-XP) and a [forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/871a145c-1b24-48e0-9ddd-ea98957d3332) about the topic. All within the first and second [google page](https://www.google.de/webhp?q=monitor%20switch%20c#), maybe you can find your answer there?